# 'super' keyword unexpected inside a generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

While trying to use super keyword inside a generator, I'm getting the following error

```
base_model.js:82
        yield super.$beforeInsert(context);
              ^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
```

Here's the source code (Transpiled via Babel)

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    $beforeInsert(context) {
        var _this = this;

        return _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
            yield super.$beforeInsert(context);
            if (_this.timestamps) {
                _this.created_at = new Date();
            }
        })();
    }
}
```

Here's the original source code

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    async $beforeInsert(context) {
        await super.$beforeInsert(context);
        if (this.timestamps) {
            this.created_at = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using node v6.3.1

Comment: Could you also add the actual source code,   this one looks like a transpiled one..

Comment: @cswl added the original source code.

Comment: My guess is that `super` needs to be called in the scope of the method. In this case, it's called in the scope of the generation function. Or, in other words: you can't "postpone" the call to `super`. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/84c0f61f776778e1d7b68cea672253a6) that will throw the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately Babel doesn't currently support compiling with `super` inside async methods if you aren't using transpiled classes. Seems like you're using a preset that excludes class transpilation. Bug filed here: http://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6895